# Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.3.2, giftmessage

On cart page I am getting this error in console:

Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component

When I disable the module Magento_GiftMessage is working but it effect some where.

Comment: have you override this js file in your theme?

Comment: no. I'm not override the file

Comment: write proper description then only someone can help you else everyone open a tag to close this question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Due to Some of your custom module it is getting error, don't disable Magento_GiftMessage, enable it and try to check your custom module disable one by one

Comment: I'm also getting this error
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message" component.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your checkout_cart_index.xml file.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="Magento_GiftMessage::cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had checkout_cart_index.xml copied to my theme folder and which was causing the issue, upon removing the file from theme folder it removed the error. Just copy the components from vendor to theme checkout_cart_index.xml which require changes.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my checkout_cart_index.xml file from my theme folder and it fixed the issue.